# KnockoutJS Mapping - Why are my arrays not mapped to observable arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have the following JSON that is being returned from an API I have built:

```
{  
   "Pages":[  
      {  
         "Name":"Page 1",
         "Controls":[  
            {  
               "LabelText":"Summary",
               "Name":"txtSummary",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Event Date:",
               "Name":"txteventdate",
               "ControlType":10,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Impact:",
               "Name":"txtimpact",
               "ControlType":14,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Probability:",
               "Name":"txtprobability",
               "ControlType":14,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Due Date:",
               "Name":"txtduedate",
               "ControlType":10,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Score:",
               "Name":"numscore",
               "ControlType":14,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Primary Needs:",
               "Name":"cboprimaryneeds1",
               "ControlType":2,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Address",
               "Name":"txtAddressLine1",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Title",
               "Name":"optionpanel1",
               "ControlType":7,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Address",
               "Name":"txtAddressLine2",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Address",
               "Name":"txtAddressLine3",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Forename",
               "Name":"txtForename",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Address",
               "Name":"txtAddressLine4",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Surname",
               "Name":"txtsurname",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Postcode",
               "Name":"txtPostcode",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"EmployeeCode",
               "Name":"txtEmployeeCode",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Decapitated",
               "Name":"chkDecapitated",
               "ControlType":3,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Age",
               "Name":"txtAge",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Football Team",
               "Name":"txtFootballTeam",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Time",
               "Name":"timeSelection1",
               "ControlType":11,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Rugby Team",
               "Name":"txtRugbyTeam",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"dtFrom",
               "Name":"dtFrom",
               "ControlType":10,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"National Insurance",
               "Name":"txtNationalInsurance",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"dtTo",
               "Name":"dtTo",
               "ControlType":10,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            },
            {  
               "LabelText":"Shoe Size",
               "Name":"txtShoeSize",
               "ControlType":0,
               "IsMultiLine":false,
               "MaxLength":null,
               "MinLength":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to use the KnockoutJS mapping plugin (v2.4.1) to automatically map this structure into a viewmodel however I am finding that even though "Pages" is an array of objects it is mapped as an observable rather than an observable array, I would like an observable array so that I can push and pop from it and have the UI update accordingly.

The Knockout Mapping documentation says this..

> "Arrays are converted into observable arrays. If an update would
>   change the number of items, it will perform the appropriate add/remove
>   actions. It will also try to keep the order the same as the original
>   JavaScript array."

Here is what my code looks like that actually does the mapping...

```
// data is json above
var mappedData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
// mappedData.Pages is an observable containing an Array[] rather than an observableArray.
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: I see nothing wrong. See http://jsfiddle.net/jo2o36cp/1. `mappedData.Pages()` is indeed an `observableArray`.

Comment: `mappedData.Pages` may look like an array, but try calling it as a function.

Comment: looks ok. see the following plnkr to illustrate http://plnkr.co/edit/Bd7Adv52QP9UywrxaDLq?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Guys, I can confirm it is working in both your fiddles but unfortunately not working for me within my application which indicates that it's likely something else causing it, I will look into this but thanks very much for having a look!